# pulling variable from between 2 modules

Tags: excel, variables, vba

I have a variable which is in my first module and i would like to use this variable in my second module.The first code is my variable.

```
    Dateiname = Ord & mNummerGanz & "_" & Name & ".xlsm"
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Dateiname
```

And i would like to use this variable in different module in same Project.

```
   Windows(Dateiname).Activate
```

Does anyone have Suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub newmodule1()
Dim Dateiname As String

Dateiname = Ord & mNummerGanz & "_" & Name & ".xlsm"
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Dateiname, fileformat:=52 
'This is just here to test the variable is stored correctly. msgbox can be removed.
MsgBox (Dateiname)

Module2.newmodule2 (Dateiname)

End Sub



Sub newmodule2(Dateiname)

'Again, this is just here to test the variable is stored correctly. msgbox can be removed.
MsgBox (Dateiname)

Windows(Dateiname).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Done, nice and simple and as little code as possible. Just the way i like it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Define it as `Public` at the top of your first module.

A simple example is below...the `Module` and `Sub` names are just made up for the example.

In **Module1**:

```
Public Dateiname As String

Private Sub SaveMyFile()
  Dateiname = Ord & mNummerGanz & "_" & Name & ".xlsm"
  ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Dateiname
End Sub
```

In **Module2**:

```
Private Sub MyOtherSub()
  Windows(Dateiname).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean over the Sub of the first module ? It doesnt work.If i put it under the Sub it gives copiling error too. Dateiname variable includes numbers and Special characters like _ . Is it because of that?

Comment: no still when i put public and declare the variable it gives an error